# Python3 and recursive class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, recursion

I want to define own tree-like class. I've written code like this:

```
class forest:
        class tree:
                def __init__(self):
                        self.var_a = []
                        self.var_b = []
                        #Or something as simple
                def mk(self,something):
                        #Some instructions
                        self.a = tree()
                        b_var = self.a.mk(a_var)
                        self.b = tree()
                        c_var = self.a.mk(b_var)
                        #Some instructions
                        return ret
        #Some code for class forest
```

Well `tree()` doesn't work.

```
NameError: global name 'tree' is not defined
```

The error for `self.tree()`:

```
AttributeError: 'tree' object has no attribute 'tree'
```

I do not know how (or if) to use `self.__init__` or `self.__new__` in this context.

**The question**
It is possible to use recursive class in Python3? How does the code for this look like?

Comment: You want `forest.tree` since the `tree` class is inside the `forest` class.

Comment: It looks it works. However, I have problems in writing simple test case...

Comment: @Michas If your question was answered, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to nest the classes in order to implement a [container pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern).

Move the *Tree* class outside of *Forest*.
Each time a tree is instantianted, it can add itself to the forest:

```
    class Forest:
            def __init__(self):
                self.mytrees = []
            def add(self, tree):
                self.mytrees.append(self)
            def drop_leaves(self):
                for tree in self.mytrees:
                    tree.drop_leaves()


    class Tree:
            def __init__(self, forest):
                forest.add(self)
                self.var_a = []
                self.var_b = []
                #Or something as simple
            def drop_leaves(self):
                print 'Drop'

    sherwood = Forest()
    t1 = Tree(sherwood)
    t2 = Tree(sherwood)
    sherwood.drop_leaves()
```

**The question:**

> It is possible to use recursive class in Python3? How does the code
>   for this look like?

**Straight answer:**

Nesting class definitions does not confer any benefit in Python because their scopes don't nest (the contents of the inner class cannot refer directly to the enclosing class).

Accordingly, the usual pattern in Python is to make two of more classes than can refer directly to one another (using composition rather than inheritance).

**Subsequent comment:**

> Well. I don't need to use classes. The functions and dictionaries
>   would be enough.

Functions and dictionaries are always enough (the early versions of Python did not have classes).  OTOH, we've found that classes are a convenient way to organize code, making it clear which functions operate on which data.  How *you* do it is a matter of taste.

**A later comment:**

> There is one benefit of nested class. Its definition doesn't reside in
>   global scope.

That can be a disadvantage as well, making it more difficult to reuse code, more difficult to test, and possibly confounding introspection tools.

Comment: Well. I don't need to use classes. The functions and dictionaries would be enough.

Comment: @Michas: That would come with huge inconveniences and be non-idiomatic. Not nesting classes is at least as convenient, and far more common in the Python world.

Comment: Well. I can use one class, dictionary and some methods (functions) inside one class.

Comment: There is one benefit of nested class. Its definition doesn't reside in global scope.

Comment: @Michas: Again, why would you? Seperate classes are cool. Nesting one into the other is not necessary.

Comment: It is uncommon to use nested classes. I agree. I think it is due to terrible implementation of few things in C++. However, if something make the code more readable in the global scope, it may be helpful in a scope of class too.

Comment: I sometimes find nested classes useful in place of creating a separate module just for namespacing purposes. E.g., I have a class `tree`, and then a class inside it which is a subclass called `deciduous` so users can just go `tree.deciduous` to access the class. Also, when I'm using metaclasses, I like to declare the metaclass directly inside the class rather than separately. But yes, the circumstances in which class nesting is arguably useful are somewhat narrow.

Comment: @Michas: Nested classes are *less* readable. It just creates confusion, as people expect the class to be defined in a global scope. Putting class definitions in other scopes are only useful (but still confusing) when you need to define the class dynamically or when the class needs a specific dynamic scope. Just nesting classes has no benefits at all, only drawbacks.

Comment: @Lennart Regebro Using more than 7 classes in global scope is confusing too. The human have limit of thinking about 7 items at once.

Comment: @Michas: But making them nested will only be *more* confusing. And it's not confusing to have more than 7 classes in the global scope, unless you have confusing naming. Most people can't keep more that 3 to 5 things in the head at once, and that doesn't stop them from using modules who has loads of classes and methods. If you want to separate the classes by namespace, I suggest using modules. Again: Nested classes *adds* confusion and complexity. There is **no benefit**.

Answer (score 0):

I just experimented with this and it can be done in Python3

```
class forest:
    #Interal Class _tree
    class _tree:
            def __init__(self):
                    self.var_a = []
                    self.var_b = []
                    #Or something as simple
            def mk(self,something):
                    #Some instructions on self.var_a or self.var_b
    def __init__(self):
        #Assign internal class _tree to public variable tree
        self.tree=self._tree()

sherwood=forest()
sherwood.tree.mk()
```

This way you don't have to pollute global name space with a 'tree' class

Though if you dislike this due to confusion/readibility issues, you can always make a separate tree class as previously described.