# Declaring a class with an instance of it inside in Python

Tags: python, class, instance

Maybe the title is a little screwed up but is there a way to make an instance of a class inside the same class in Python?

Something like this:

```
class Foo:
    foo = Foo()
```

I know that the interpreter says that Foo is not declared but is there a way to achieve this?

**Update:**

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
class NPByteRange (Structure): 
    _fields_ = [ ('offset', int32), 
                 ('lenght', uint32), 
                 ('next', POINTER(NPByteRange)) ]
```

Comment: This is kind of infinitely recursive... what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: One has to wonder why you would want to create an infinite loop of Class instantiation ?

Comment: Possible duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370472/python3-and-recursive-class

Comment: @ChristianWitts I think [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10823633/418413) illustrates one example where you might want an infinite recurrence: Beer.

Comment: On your update, do you mean to create a reference to the `NPByteRange` class, or to a new `NPByteRange` instance?

Comment: You may also want to read about other approaches to [linked lists in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280243).

Answer (score 4):

The interpreter only minds if you try to do it in a context where `Foo` is not declared. There are contexts where it is. The simplest example is in a method:

```
>>> class Beer(object):
...   def have_another(self):
...     return Beer()
... 
>>> x=Beer()
>>> x.have_another()
<__main__.Beer object at 0x10052e390>
```

If its important that the object be a property, you can just use the `property` builtin.

```
>>> class Beer(object):
...   @property
...   def another(self):
...     return Beer()
... 
>>> guinness=Beer()
>>> guinness.another
<__main__.Beer object at 0x10052e610>
```

Finally, if it's truly necessary that it be a *class* property, well, [you can do that, too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128573/using-property-on-classmethods).

Comment: @user1426948 That comment should be part of your question, not a comment on an answer.

Comment: @user1426948 is there some reason the `_fields_` property can't be an instance property or set at `__init__` time?

Comment: Well I'm still not sure of it, I'm just doing some experiments but I'll try that and let you know.