# How can I do recursive composition of classes in Python?

Tags: python, xml, deserialization

Suppose, I need to read the following XML into a python object using [`lxml`-library](https://lxml.de/index.html):

```
<detaileddescription>
    <para>
        <parameterlist kind="param">
            <parameteritem>
                <parameternamelist>
                    <parametername>parameters</parametername>
                </parameternamelist>
                <parameterdescription>
                    <para>- parameters of the distribution</para>
                </parameterdescription>
            </parameteritem>
        </parameterlist>
    </para>        
</detaileddescription>
```

So, I created the following classes:

#### ParaTag.py

```
from ParameterListTag import ParameterListTag

class ParaTag:
    parameterListTag: ParameterListTag
    text: str

    def __init__(self):
        self.parameterListTag = None
        self.text = None
```

#### ParameterDescriptionTag.py

```
from ParaTag import ParaTag


class ParameterDescriptionTag:
    text: str
    paraTag: ParaTag

    def __init__(self):
        self.text = None
        self.paraTag = None
```

#### ParameterListTag.py

```
from ParameterDescriptionTag import ParameterDescriptionTag


class ParameterListTag:
    parameterDescTag: ParameterDescriptionTag
    text: str

    def __init__(self):
        self.parameterDescTag = None
        self.text = None
```

My target is to read the XML through the **`lxml`** library and then map the read tags into respective classes.

The following is the driver program:

#### MainClass.py

```
from ParaTag import ParaTag

class MainClass:
    @classmethod
    def main(cls):
        para_obj = ParaTag()
        print(para_obj)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainClass.main()
```

However, this doesn't execute:

#### Output

```
C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.7.exe C:/Users/pc/source/repos/OOP_in_python/MainClass.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/pc/source/repos/OOP_in_python/MainClass.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ParaTag import ParaTag
  File "C:\Users\pc\source\repos\OOP_in_python\ParaTag.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ParameterListTag import ParameterListTag
  File "C:\Users\pc\source\repos\OOP_in_python\ParameterListTag.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ParameterDescriptionTag import ParameterDescriptionTag
  File "C:\Users\pc\source\repos\OOP_in_python\ParameterDescriptionTag.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ParaTag import ParaTag
ImportError: cannot import name 'ParaTag' from 'ParaTag' (C:\Users\pc\source\repos\OOP_in_python\ParaTag.py)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

**So, how can I solve this issue?**

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/204476/how-to-design-a-composite-pattern-in-python) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370472/python3-and-recursive-class) posts could be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have circular dependency. If I'm reading your code correctly ParaTag references ParaListTag which references ParaDescriptionTag which references ParaTag again.

[https://www.yawintutor.com/importerror-cannot-import-name/#:~:text=The%20python%20ImportError%3A%20cannot%20import,used%20to%20load%20the%20module](https://www.yawintutor.com/importerror-cannot-import-name/#:%7E:text=The%20python%20ImportError%3A%20cannot%20import,used%20to%20load%20the%20module).

This link does a better job of explaining why that is allowed than I can but the key paragraph is

"The other reason is that the load dependence is circular. If two python files refer to each other and try to load the other file, then the circular load dependency will be established. That will cause heap memory error. Python detects and throws the error ImportError: Can’t Import Name."

What Mauro Baraldi's links are pointing out is that you need to find a different way to structure your class.